# Listen to all notifications like `LISTEN *`

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to listen to all notification that are broadcast by Postgress? For example something like `LISTEN *` without having to create any ad-hoc channels like `all_channels`? I need this to minimize the number of active connection that are listening to notifications. Imagine that there would be 200 channels, this approach can actually minimize the number of active connections to only 1 for capturing all notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Try to come up with a design that needs fewer channels – perhaps you can differentiate via the payload of the notification:

```
NOTIFY channel, '4711';
```

Comment: Laurenz, you somehow give me back exactly my own current solutions :D. I can't down vote your answers (joking) though because somehow you make clear that these challenges are limitations of Postgre.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally click on downvote, please make an edit to your answer so I can upvote it.